# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS com armazenamento e processamento em 100%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Estou com um problema no meu servidor de desenvolvimento e não consigo consertar.
Já pesquisei bastante, porém não encontro a solução. Provavelmente quem tem um conhecimento mais avançado do SO acredito que poderia ajudar muito:
Estava desenvolvendo um bash script e em um momento do código tive que implementar deleção de arquivos, mas meu script **executou um `rm -f` com o valor de variável (*acidentalmente*)**.

Minha sorte é que o comando exclui apenas arquivos `.tmp` e `.save` para excluir arquivos gerados pelo nano. Porém como o comando rodou na raiz, comecei a experimentar os seguintes problemas no SO:

1. o armazenamento /dev/vda1 vai a 100% de uso depois de algumas horas
   com a maquina ligada.
2. Quando o armazenamento está cheio o uso de CPU também vai a 100%
   sendo o programa sh o consumidor do processamento.
3. Quando reinicio a maquina tudo funciona normalmente.
4. Depois de um tempo volta a acontecer tudo de novo.

O que fiz pra tentar resolver foi:

1. Atualizei com apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade. **Problema
   persiste.**
2. Esse Ubuntu era 16.04, atualizei para 18.04.1 com
   do-release-upgrade. **Ocorreram alguns erros de atualização de
   headers.**
3. Tentei reinstalar os headers com apt upgrade --fix-missing. **Problema
   persiste.**

Enfim, parei por aqui e resolvi pedir ajuda da comunidade, peço que me ajudem a consertar esse servidor, seria muito desgastante ter que reconfigurar todos os serviços em uma nova máquina e talvez esse post possa ajudar alguém no futuro com esse mesmo problema.
Estou disposto a fazer todos os testes necessários.